# editing csv file

Tags: macos, bash, csv, terminal

We received 18,000 CSV files, each with 2 lines of text.

These two lines were supposed to be a single line, separated by a comma.

> FK1QG5QL
>   b8:9d:7d

should appear

> FK1QG5QL,b8:9d:7d

I'm trying to remove the return from the first line and replace it with a comma.

Comment: question was edited. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this one work?

```
for f in *.csv; do awk 'BEGIN {l=""} !/^ *$/ {if (l!="") {l=l","}; l=l$0} END {print l}' "$f"; done
```

You can redirect the output of the above command to a file:

```
for f in *.csv; do awk 'BEGIN {l=""} !/^ *$/ {if (l!="") {l=l","}; l=l$0} END {print l}' "$f"; done > combined
```

If you want to change every single file you can use the next version. It will create another file called *.copy:

```
for f in *.csv; do awk 'BEGIN {l=""} !/^ *$/ {if (l!="") {l=l","}; l=l$0} END {print l}' "$f" > "$f".copy; done
```

Comment: wouldn't that only work if these were the file names?

Comment: If I understood you correctly: you have 18000 CSV files with two lines in each one of them, and you want to combine each line in each file into a single line, separated by a comma. Is that correct? The command in my answer takes the list of files in the current directory, reads them and returns all lines in each file combined into one line, separated by a comma.

Comment: what's creating the separate output file (without overwriting the original file?) AND of course, UUOC, `awk '...script' $f` is more efficient. Good luck to all.

Comment: yes. titles are "device info 1.csv, device info 2.csv, device info 3.csv in a folder on my desktop called "CSVs" Sorry, I'm kinda new to scripting.

Comment: I changed my answer a little bit. The first command will only print the required output to the screen. You can use it safely.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the command `paste`?

```
for f in *; do
   mv "$f" "$f.bak" && paste -sd "," "$f.bak" > "$f"
done
# test first before uncommenting next line
# rm *.bak
```

Without paste you can try other solutions:

```
head -1 input.csv | tr '\n' ',' ; tail -1 input.csv

cat input.csv | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/,$/\n/'

printf -v oneline "%s," $(cat input.csv); echo "${oneline%,}"

sed 'N;s/\n/,/' input.csv

set -- $(cat input.csv); IFS=,; echo "$*"
```